# pst-node replacement for LuaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, pstricks, pst-node

I have code that uses pst-node package to draw overbrace. What package should i use to compile it with LuaTeX?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
    $\overset{\rnode{C}{\scriptstyle c}}{410}\text{ pounds} +
    \overset{\rnode{V}{\scriptstyle v}}{90}\text{ pounds}$
\ncarc[angleB=180]{C}{V}
\end{document}
```

[MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/cxkvhrfrtfdk)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a pretty close result with TikZ:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]


    $\overset{c \tikz[na] \coordinate (c-node);}{410}\text{ pounds} +
    \overset{\tikz[na] \coordinate (v-node); v }{90}\text{ pounds}$

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[-,black] (c-node) edge [out=5,in=175] (v-node);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

needs only `lualatex --shell-escape <file>`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf-lua}

\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
    $\overset{\rnode{C}{\scriptstyle c}}{410}\text{ pounds} +
    \overset{\rnode{V}{\scriptstyle v}}{90}\text{ pounds}$
    \ncarc[angleB=180]{C}{V}
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I use the brace in inline math node. So i need to compile postscript the whole paragraph? `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. $\overset{\rnode{C}{\scriptstyle c}}{410}\text{ pounds} +
    \overset{\rnode{V}{\scriptstyle v}}{90}\text{ pounds}$ Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get (not really surprising) error messages from dvips `dvips: Can't open font metric file [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;.tfm
dvips: I will use cmr10.tfm instead, so expect bad output.` and glyphs are missing. The code contains a reference to a package `pst-pdf-lua` but this is never loaded (and also seems not to exist).

Comment: @DenysPotapov: Only the PSTricks part must be in the `postscript` environment. Not the complete paragraph.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I see, wrong package name, but has nothing to do with your problem.